# Laravel TailwindCSS Adding more colors not working

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-jetstream

In my case, I want to add more colors from the TailwindCSS Palette. The versions I've got now are:

```
├── @tailwindcss/forms@0.3.3
├── @tailwindcss/typography@0.4.1
└── tailwindcss@2.2.15
```

Here is my tailwind.config.js file:

**tailwind.config.js**

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit',
    purge: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './vendor/laravel/jetstream/**/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Nunito', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
            colors: {
                transparent: 'transparent',
                current: 'currentColor',
                amber: colors.amber,
                black: colors.black,
                blue: colors.blue,
                cyan: colors.cyan,
                emerald: colors.emerald,
                fuchsia: colors.fuchsia,
                gray: colors.trueGray,
                blueGray: colors.blueGray,
                coolGray: colors.coolGray,
                trueGray: colors.trueGray,
                warmGray: colors.warmGray,
                green: colors.green,
                indigo: colors.indigo,
                lime: colors.lime,
                orange: colors.orange,
                pink: colors.pink,
                purple: colors.purple,
                red: colors.red,
                rose: colors.rose,
                sky: colors.sky,//warn - As of Tailwind CSS v2.2, `lightBlue` has been renamed to `sky`.
                teal: colors.teal,
                violet: colors.violet,
                yellow: colors.amber,
                white: colors.white,
            },
        },
    },

    plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms'), require('@tailwindcss/typography')],
};
```

Then I ran `npm run dev` and deleted my Firefox caché.

The following color classes do work:

- bg-amber-600
- bg-green-600
- bg-indigo-600
- bg-blue-600
- bg-orange-600
- bg-sky-600
- bg-red-600
- bg-yellow-600

However, the following colors **do not work**:

- bg-black-600
- bg-fuchsia-600
- bg-gray-600
- bg-emerald-600
- bg-cyan-600
- bg-lime-600
- bg-pink-600
- bg-purple-600
- bg-rose-600
- bg-teal-600
- bg-violet-600
- bg-blueGray-600
- bg-coolGray-600
- bg-trueGray-600
- bg-warmGray-600

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ]);

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

Why is this happening? How do I fix it? Then how do I import all the colors? Can't all the colors be imported?

Answer (score 1):

These are the colors you are getting https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/src/public/colors.js

bg-black-600 for instance doesn't exist, there are no shades of black in default tailwind, only shades of gray and some of them have getters for alternative names

If you aren't getting those you can try console logging the colors you are importing and see if your dependency is correct.

If some still aren't working you can just manually copy the js into your config file. I would also do a quick search in your CSS bundle to 100% check that the colors are there. Also as a final debug you can check the CSS that is used in your browser by looking through the dev tools to check the CSS sheet that is getting fetched (A string search for something like `bg-rose-600` would work)

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, when I search for `bg-rose` inside the `public/css/app.css` the color is not there. How do I manually copy the js into my config file? Maybe there's an additional action I should do? Laravel mix?